# Change tracking to show before and after value

Tags: sql, change-tracking

So I enabled change tracking on the database and table and ran the below query;

```
SELECT * 
FROM CHANGETABLE(CHANGES Cust, 0) AS CT
```

[image: Data returned from query above]

This returns valuable information that I can use but I am wondering if there is a way that I can show the value before and after the change?

For example - If the customer table has a name column and I change that column from 'Facebook' to 'Twitter'.  That I can then see the before value (Facebook) and after value (Twitter).

Comment: Please specifiy the dbms. Generally in sql server it can be done via Change data capture(CDC).Please see the below link for an idea https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/learn-sql-server/introduction-to-change-data-capture-cdc-in-sql-server-2008/

Comment: This instance of SQL Server is the Express Edition (64-bit). Change data capture is only available in the Enterprise, Developer, Enterprise Evaluation, and Standard editions. (That answers the question, I guess CDC not available on Express edition).

Comment: yes CDC not avialable in express edition. so in this case i think the best option is to implement trigger in the table which you want to monitor changes.

Comment: Great.  I'll do it via triggers.  Just thought there was something such as CDC (There is, CDC!) but not available on Express. Thanks.